# How to get Beeline command line interface recognize up arrow key press

Tags: hive, terminal, command-line-interface, beeline

When working on Hive queries through Beeline command line interface, I can't get the upper arrow (and other arrows, mouse wheel up/down, page up/down) to work. It simply shows

```
0: jdbc:hive2://remoteserver:10000> ^[[A^[[B^[[D^[[C^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[B^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A
```

If I exit and back to my bash shell CLI, the upper arrow (and other key press functions) works fine.

It becomes annoying as I need to retype historic queries all the time. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Solved: for those in similar situations, here is my work-around. The server seems to have readline library installed, but somehow my account was not set up to use readline properly. Thus I installed https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/blob/master/INSTALL and use "rlwrap -a beeline" instead.

Comment: For upper arrow to get command history, the CLI has to use something like readline – does Beeline use readline?

Comment: I don't know if Beeline is using readline or not. How should I check? btw I have no admin permission on the remote server.

Comment: I mean, it could just be that Beeline doesn't support that kind of functionality period.

Comment: could be. It works for some other users on the server. Too bad I am the unlucky one:(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a terminal program to honour cursor keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187219/how-do-i-get-a-terminal-program-to-honour-cursor-keys) (this is a generic problem, not programming *per se*, but **`rlwrap`** provides a solution).